# How to add two buttons with independent functionality in Ajax using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two buttons "insert" and "select" which are used to insert and display the records using AJAX and I want that both of them should have independent functionality, as in, whenever I click select button the records should be displayed and when I click insert, records should be inserted. Right now in the code below, second button which is select is dependent upon click of insert button. I want then to work independently.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#insert').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url:"back1.php",
            method:"post",
            data:$('form').serialize(),
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(strMsg)
            {
                $('#select').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                $.ajax({
                url:"back1.php",
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(strMsg)
                {
                    $('#Smsg').html(strMsg);    
                }                   
                    });


                });

                $('#Imsg').html(strMsg);

            }


        });  
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: They are depended because you define the method for the select button in the success function of the insert button.

Comment: @axel.michel I could figure out the same but don't know how to make them independent. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the comment above, the functionality is depended because you defined the event handler for the select button inside the success method of the insert button.

Which might be logically correct by the way: In case you'll need a response from the insert request before triggering the select request. In that case, there should be such a dependency. Anyway if this is not the case, simply move the event handler to the outside:

```
// when everything is ready...
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // first event handler
    $('#insert').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"back1.php",
                method:"post",
                data:$('form').serialize(),
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(strMsg) {
                    $('#Imsg').html(strMsg);
                }
        });  
    });

    // second (independent) one
    $('#select').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            url:"back1.php",
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(strMsg) {
                $('#Smsg').html(strMsg);    
            }
        });
    });
});
```

A few more things - I would suggest the usage of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), instead of `click`:

```
$('#select').on('click', function(event){...});
```

And try to avoid code repetition, in your case, you could do something like:

```
function AjaxEventHandler(data, targetObject) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"back1.php",
        method:"post",
        data: data,
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(strMsg) {
            targetObject.html(strMsg);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#insert').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        AjaxEventHandler($('form').serialize(), $('#Imsg'))
    });

    $('#select').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        AjaxEventHandler({}, $('#Smsg'))
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer. Appreciate your help.